# matrix multiplication error between 3d and 2d

Tags: matlab

I am performing 3d matrix multiplication with 2d but getting error

```
[a b c] = size(im_f);
[a d]= size(H);

im_nf = zeros([a d c]);

im_nf = cellfun(@(im_f) im_f*H,mat2cell(im_f,a,b,ones(1,c)),'UniformOutput',false);
im_nf = cat(3,im_nf{:});
```

but it is giving error:

```
??? Error using ==> mtimes
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in ==> homofil>@(im_f)im_f*H at 27

im_nf = cellfun(@(im_f) im_f*H,mat2cell(im_f,a,b,ones(1,c)),'UniformOutput',false);`???             Error using ==> mtimes
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in ==> homofil>@(im_f)im_f*H at 27
im_nf = cellfun(@(im_f) im_f*H,mat2cell(im_f,a,b,ones(1,c)),'UniformOutput',false);
```

`homofil` is file name

size of `im_f` is `[ 307   409     3 ]`

size of `H` is `[ 307        1227 ]`

How can this error be corrected?

Comment: Obviously multiplying a 3D matrix by a 2D will give you an error.  What do you **expect** to happen?  Give us an example of the inputs and outputs you are expecting.

Comment: i want an answer of size [307 1227 3]

Comment: @sheelumishra no way you are going to multiply a 307-by-1227 matrix (`H`) and a 307-by-409 matrix (`im_f`) and get a 307-by-1227 result. No matter how you order/transpose the inputs.

Comment: Instead of telling us **what** you are trying to do with the operations, why don't you tell us what **application** you are doing instead. **Why** do you need to multiply the matrices this way? This way, we can suggest alternatives instead of you trying to break one of the laws of linear algebra for multiplying matrices.

Answer (score 1):

In the `cellfun` you are trying to multiply `im_f` of size `[307 409]` by `H` of size `[307 1227]` - this is why you have "Inner matrix dimensions must agree" error.

Either change the order of `im_f` and `H`:

```
im_nf = cellfun(@(im_f) H*im_f,mat2cell(im_f,a,b,ones(1,c)),'UniformOutput',false);
```

Or transpose `im_f`:

```
im_nf = cellfun(@(im_f) im_f.'*H,mat2cell(im_f,a,b,ones(1,c)),'UniformOutput',false);
```

BTW, nice usage of `mat2cell` and `cellfun` ;)

Comment: still its giving error error in the matrix
    `??? Error using ==> times
    Matrix dimensions must agree.

    Error in ==> homofil>@(im_f)im_f.*H at 29
    im_nf = cellfun(@(im_f)    H.*im_f,mat2cell(im_f,a,b,ones(1,c)),'UniformOutput',false);

    Error in ==> homofil at 29
    im_nf = cellfun(@(im_f)       H.*im_f,mat2cell(im_f,a,b,ones(1,c)),'UniformOutput',false);`

Comment: @sheelumishra please pay close attention: you omitted the transpose operator `'` after the `.`! you need to have `im_f.' * H` and **not** `im_f .* H`!

Comment: may be doing transpose transpose is affecting my resultant image size

Comment: @sheelumishra - Instead of telling us what you are trying to do with the operations, why don't you tell us what **application** you are doing instead.  **Why** do you need to multiply the matrices this way?  This way, we can suggest alternatives instead of you trying to break one of the laws of linear algebra for multiplying matrices

Comment: @rayryeng can you move your comment to the question? I feel it is more appropriate there...